Maven compatibility Issue Java 21
I am trying to build a Java Spring Boot project for my staging environment.
I am using Java 21 on Ubuntu System (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS)

When executing my following staging shell script
   #!/bin/bash

cd ./

# Log Java and Maven versions for debugging
echo "Java version:"
java -version

echo "Maven version:"
mvn -v

# Install Maven if not already installed
if ! [ -x "$(command -v mvn)" ]; then
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install maven -y
fi

# Install the AWS CLI if not already installed
if ! [ -x "$(command -v aws)" ]; then
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install awscli -y
fi

# Build API
mvn clean package -Pstaging -e

# Check the build status
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "API successfully built"

else
  echo "Failed to build API"
fi

exit

I get the following error
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project api: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 21 not supported -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project api: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:333)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:314)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:314)
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: error: release version 21 not supported
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:198)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1140)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:314)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error: release version 21 not supported
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.reportDiag (Arguments.java:886)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.handleReleaseOptions (Arguments.java:312)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.processArgs (Arguments.java:351)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.init (Arguments.java:247)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask (JavacTool.java:191)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask (JavacTool.java:119)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask (JavacTool.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:135)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1140)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:314)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Failed to build API

I have double-checked my Intellij IDE setting and can't find the problem any suggestions where to look?
Java Compiler
Maven Settings



Project Settings

Project SDK

When running mvn -v

My pom.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.detect</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>2024.11.12</version>
    <name>detect-api</name>
    <description>De-Tect API</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <activeProfile>dev</activeProfile>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>staging</id>
            <properties>
                <activeProfile>staging</activeProfile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <activeProfile>prod</activeProfile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.33</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230227</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sesv2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.slack.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>slack-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.27.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>api</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>build/${activeProfile}/${project.version}</outputDirectory>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <finalName>api</finalName>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What does your pom.xml look like?

@kidney I've updated my question with my pom code attached.

Managed to solve the issue
I had to set my Shell script Environmental variable to the correct JAVA_HOME path

The issue error: release version 21 not supported  shows that you are not using JDK 21 to build... furthermore why defining profiles which are spring profiles? They should be separated... Maven profiles is a different thing than a spring profiles... Also why using the maven-assembly-plugin? Use the spring-boot-maven-plugin ....
